# What does PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention do?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm learning code first and I'm going over the default conventions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696316(v=vs.103).aspx), and I'm wondering what `PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention` does. I understand it pluralizes something, like `PluralizingTableNameConvention`, but what does it pluralize exactly? Can you give an example where the effects of this convention would be noticeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be to do with the name to be used in creating navigation properties
ie Person to People vs Person to Persons. I think this is relevant when you are using a designer to generate code.